# ¿Cómo mostrar solo un dato relacionado en relación hasMany con Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, querybuilder

Hola a todos espero se encuentren bien. Estoy haciendo un proyecto en laravel 8, tengo 2 modelos Post e Image, Post tiene relacion hasMany con Image, Image tiene relación belongsTo con Post, estoy intentando mostrar los posts y una imagen (cualquiera) con mi api rest, aquí el código de la consulta para obtener los posts:

```
    public function index()
{
    //
    

    $post = Post::distinct()->
    join('post_images','post_images.post_id','=','posts.id')->
    join('categories','categories.id','=','posts.category_id')->
    select('posts.*','categories.title as category','post_images.image')->distinct()->
    orderBy('posts.created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
    
    $x=$post;
    foreach ($x as $key => $posts) {
        $posts["image"]= Storage::URL($posts["image"]);
    }

    return $this->successResponse($post);
}
```

Mi problema es que cuando un post tiene 2 imágenes, en el código json recibo ese post duplicado con el campo image diferente, algo así:

```
{
id: 404,
title: "probando relación",
url_clean: "probando-relacion",
content: "<p>probando relación</p>",
posted: "not",
category_id: 1,
created_at: "2021-04-08T21:43:24.000000Z",
updated_at: "2021-04-08T21:43:24.000000Z",
category: "Categoria 1",
image: "/storage/SbSZWLn83MEFPHKU1UQU3W0aAqpNTlbDGhUvmyoH.jpg"
},
{
id: 404,
title: "probando relación",
url_clean: "probando-relacion",
content: "<p>probando relación</p>",
posted: "not",
category_id: 1,
created_at: "2021-04-08T21:43:24.000000Z",
updated_at: "2021-04-08T21:43:24.000000Z",
category: "Categoria 1",
image: "/storage/fv1mNp3dbvKggx1cpwPf3E3sB6hw3ItpcS1JKmzV.jpg"
}
```

Y solo quiero mostrar uno, como puedo hacerlo?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @BetaM, lo segundo que dijiste, para cada post que tenga mas de 1 imagen, solo quiero mostrar 1 sola imagen, por ejemplo la ultima que se añadió.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes resolver esto a través de:

- Una consulta *join* como lo vienes haciendo y luego una subquery que te filtre por la fecha mas alta de creación de cada registro de imagen
- A nivel de Eloquent puedes incluso hacerlo a través de eager loading
- O mediante una subconsulta (*que es lo que esta respuesta mostrará*)

Tu consulta podría quedar de este modo:

```
Post::addSelect(['imagen_reciente' => Image::select('image')
    ->whereColumn('posts.id', 'post_images.post_id')
    ->latest()
    ->limit(1)
])->get();
```

Que a nivel de SQL se vería así:

```
select `posts`.*, (select `image` from `post_images` 
                   where `posts`.`id` = `post_images`.`post_id` 
                   order by `created_at` desc 
                   limit 1) as `imagen_reciente` 
from `posts`
```

Básicamente es:

- De los posts hace un *select* general
- Por medio de la subquery filtramos a la foto mas reciente estableciendo el primer criterio de evaluar donde llave primaria se corresponda con una llave foránea
- Además el siguiente criterio ordena de manera descendente por fecha y limitamos el resultado a una sola fila por post

**Enlaces de referencia**

- [*Advanced subqueries*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries)